# How to boot Android Emulator with more than 16 cpus

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-emulator, qemu

I'd like to boot Android on Emulator with more than 16 cpus.

### Debug step:

1. I configured `Kernel Features-->Maximum number of CPUs to 128`. Then I changed android qemu hw/arm/ranchu.c mc->max_cpus to 128 too.
2. Start Android with: 
    `emulator -avd test_wzh -show-kernel   -skip-adb-auth -no-snapshot -kernel /root/wangzhh/image/Image -no-window  -writable-system -partition-size 65536  -verbose -gpu host  -qemu   -enable-kvm -m 16384  -realtime mlock=off -smp 32,sockets=32,cores=1,threads=1`
3. Check cpu in the guest: 
   `adb -s emulator-5554 shell` 
   Only 16 cpus online, all the cpu after index 16 shows same error log
4. Printk to debug kernel
   I traced the kernel code and found the error report by
   [`psci_to_linux_errno` case PSCI_RET_INVALID_ADDRESS](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/goldfish/+/refs/heads/android-goldfish-4.4-dev/drivers/firmware/psci.c#137)

### Kernel log:

...                             
Detected VIPT I-cache on CPU15                             
CPU15: found redistributor f region 0:0x0000000008280000   
Invalid sched_group_energy for CPU15                       
CPU15: update cpu_capacity 1024                            
CPU15: Booted secondary processor [481fd010]               
psci: failed to boot CPU16 (-22)                           
CPU16: failed to boot: -22                                 
...

Thanks to anyone who can help!
Also, I guess it related to the dts, but I don't know which dts used by android emulator, who knows this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As explained here (https://github.com/intel/haxm/issues/195) HAXM supports up to 16 VCPUs, but you can download source code from GitHub (https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases), change specific variable/constant in the Source, recompile it and replace existent binary/library.

Or you have to change Emulator to something different (KVM?).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know - you can only set a max of 4 sockets. So you might wanna change from:

```
-smp 32,sockets=32,cores=1,threads=1
```

to:

```
-smp 32,sockets=1,cores=32,threads=1
```